# Comparing and updating a sheet in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I am a student currently doing a vacation job at a company and have been tasked with maintaining and updating a database. The database is created on an excel spreadsheet. Now the issue that I am having is that I am unable to run a comparison.
In one workbook I have 2 sheets. Sheet 1 has 6 columns and sheet 2 has only 4 columns. I want to compare column A in sheet 1 and sheet 2, and if they are the same sheet, let sheet 2 values become those in sheet 1. That I can do, however, if column A from sheet 1 does not equal column A from sheet 2 the entire row from sheet 2 must be copied into sheet 1.

```
If A1 = A2 Then
       B1 = B2
       C1 = C2
       D1 = D2
Else
       'add into first empty row in sheet 1.
```

Your help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: start by reading about `VLookup` , not sure you need VBA for this, a simple formula of `VLookup` will do

Comment: Do you want to copy in the entire row to sheet1 from sheet2 despite there being a different amount of columns?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.
This code will compare the data form column a in sheet 2 to the data from column a in sheet 1 and if they are the same, the first 4 column values in that row will be copied.

```
sub test
application.screenupdating = false
For i = 1 to x 'number of rows you want to search in
For j = 2 to 4
If sheets("sheet1").range("A"&i).value = sheets("sheet2").range("A"&i).value
then sheets("sheet2").Cells(i,j).value = sheets("sheet1").Cells(i,j).value
next j
next i
end sub
```

Tested and worked